# How to implement a graph with customizable nodes with Core Data?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, data-structures

I am trying to create a core data application with an underlying directed acyclic graph structure. Thus every node has an "to many" relationship to its children nodes, and a reverse "to many" relationship to its parents nodes.

This is all pretty easy with Core Data so far. What I am having trouble with is allowing these nodes to be customizable.

To elaborate, I really like the API associated with Sublime Text and how much functionality users have. I want to allow users to define node types on this graph. A user might create a node called a "Movie Rating" defined using JSON like so:

```
{
    "type": "Movie Rating",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "Movie",
        "type": "str",
        "required": "true",
        "min-length": "1",
    }, {
        "name": "Rating",
        "type": "int",
        "required": "true",
        "min": 1,
        "max": 5
    }]
}
```

There could be any number of attributes and many different types of nodes. If I wanted to implement this sort of flexible data structure with Core Data, how might I go about doing this?

(note that every node will have parent-child relationships along with any custom fields/attributes).

Thanks

Chet

Comment: Duplicate of [Customize core data model at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379025/customize-core-data-model-at-runtime) ?

Comment: No, this has to do with implementing a directed acyclic graph structure

Answer (score 2):

You can't just modify the Core Data model on the fly. But to a degree, you can have an extensible model by

- Creating one or more simple entity types that just store an `NSString` key and some kind of value object. You may want more than one depending on how many different types of values you want to support. A simple example would have an `NSString` key and value and a to-one relationship to a node entity.
- Adding a to-many relationship from your node entity to this key/value entity.

That much allows each node to have as many key/value pairs as you want. Different nodes can have different combinations of pairs. They're not really different as far as Core Data goes but your app logic can treat them as effectively being different node types.

If you'll use more than one value type (and it looks like you might) you could create an abstract entity type called `KeyValuePair` with type-specific sub-entities like `KeyValuePairString`, `KeyValuePairNumber`, etc.

To use something like your JSON example to manage typing (so the nodes don't contain just any arbitrary key/value collection) you'd need to

- Store the node contents information in an `NSDictionary` (possibly one that you create by parsing the JSON that you include above).
- Use a convenience constructor for your nodes that takes this dictionary as an argument and creates both the node and the necessary key/value pair objects described in the dictionary.
- Be *very* careful about allowing modifications to the node description. If you later decide to add a "year" field to the movie rating, what then? It's up to you, both to figure out what should happen and to write the code (if any) to make it happen. You won't be able to rely on Core Data model versioning.

Following your movie rating example, when creating a new instance you might end up with something like

- One instance of `Node` whose attributes include the parent/child node relationship, a reference to the "Movie Rating" node definition (maybe just a name, maybe some kind of object reference) and a to-many relationship to the `KeyValuePair` entity mentioned above.
- One related `KeyValuePair` where the key is "name" and the value is "Star Wars"
- A second related `KeyValuePair` where the key is "rating" and the value is 5.

But note that you'll have to write any code that's necessary to ensure that you don't violate the node description-- for example by taking a node defined by your "movie rating" description and adding arbitrary other key/value pairs that don't make sense (e.g. adding a numeric "weight" k/v pair to the movie rating probably doesn't make sense, but Core Data isn't going to help you prevent that).

This all may be kind of awkward-- you're essentially implementing a higher-level data schema on top of Core Data. With some care it should be possible, though.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Awkward indeed. Would you recommend this approach though? I think this could work, but I'm afraid of the unknown because this feels kind of like a hack...

Comment: It's, well *something* of a hack. I don't think there are any significant drawbacks, but it will require some care. One nice thing is that you can easily search all k/v pairs by value to find specific items. You might want to consider alternatives to Core Data like [YapDatabase](https://github.com/yaptv/YapDatabase) that are more k/v oriented in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To change attributes or relationships you need to modify the `managedObjectModel` of your managed object context with the new/updated/deleted `NSEntityDescription` objects.

Managed object models are editable until they are used by an object graph manager (a managed object context or a persistent store coordinator). This allows you to create or modify them dynamically. However, once a model is being used, it must not be changed. This is enforced at runtime—when the object manager first fetches data using a model, the whole of that model becomes uneditable. Any attempt to mutate a model or *any of its sub-objects* after that point causes an exception to be thrown. If you need to modify a model that is in use, create a copy, modify the copy, and then migrate the objects from the old model.

The whole process is detailed in [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)